# If $\int_{a}^{b} f \cdot g = f(a) \int_{a}^{b} g$, then $f(c) = g(c)$ for some $c \in (a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f : [a, b ] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $g$ Riemann integrable such that $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [ a, b] $ prove that if $\int_{a}^{b} f \cdot g = f(a) \int_{a}^{b} g$ then there exist $c \in (a, b) $ such that $f(c) = g(c) $

My teacher suggested to use the mean value theorem for integrals.

I know that the mean value theorem for integrals is only applicable to continuous functions so $\int_{a}^{b} f = (b-a) f(c)$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. My problem is that I don't see how to use the hypothesis to reach the conclusion, only that advice would suffice.

Comment: Hi Evariste (lol). What have you tried? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: Sorry for my English, I know that the mean value theorem for integrals is only applicable to continuous functions so $  \int_{a}^{b} f = (b-a) f(c) $ for some $c \in (a , b)$ my problem is that I don't see how use the hypothesis to reach the conclusion, only that advice would suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. If $f$ is any constant function then  the hypothesis is satisfied. If the constant value of $f$ is not in the range of $g$ then we cannot have $f(c)=g(c)$. For a specific example take $f \equiv 1$ and $g \equiv 2$.